# How can I make emacs ignore bell when recording macros?

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp

Currently, emacs will halt the recording of a macro when the bell rings. This is extremely useful for things like halting when `C-s` fails to get a new match.

However, when I'm recording a macro, and I make a typo in my search, or I’m writing some complex macro in general, halting the recording of a macro is a pain.

I'd like to be able to have the recording carry on, and allow (or even prompt me) to fix the macro after recording.

Is there a way of doing this? There are no obvious variables, or packages etc

Comment: If you take a look at the function that you triggered to cause the bill to ring, then you will likely find the function contains an `(error . . .` function, which is what stops your macro recording in its tracks.  The bell likely follows the error message.  Take a look at `ignore-errors` as a possible means of wrapping your macro function.  A better solution would be to write a function instead using a macro if you intend on using it more than a couple of times.